# iOS WebView drawing after updating the DOM issue

Tags: javascript, ios, dom, webview, drawing

I'm using WKWebView to show a webpage in an iOS app (which is of course trivial).

When the page loads I am hiding the webview, updating some of the DOM in the site using javascript injection (`evaluateJavaScript`) - I am hiding certain elements - and then showing the page.

I do not want the user to see the elements I have hidden but it seems when the webview draws it first draws the page with the elements and then shows them being removed even though I have removed them already (I do a javascript check to make sure they are gone as well).

Does anyone know why this might be happening and what I can do to fix it?

Is the OS buffering draw requests until the view is actually viewable?

EDIT: the only way around this at the moment is to put in a 2.5 second delay to give the page time to update. This is a bad solution and I'd like a more elegant one.